# Always add commit author and date in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit on Windows, and I'm wondering how can I set it up so that it always adds the commit author and date.

In other terms, could these two checkboxes be on by default ?

[image]

I'm sort of new to git, so maybe someone will tell me that this is useless or not recommended.

Comment: commit date and author are always set. you only need those checkboxes if you want to set a date that is not "now" or want to reset it when amending the previous commit

Comment: I see, thanks. Write this as answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The commit and author date and name are always set whenever you commit (this is a Git requirement); they default to "now" and whatever you set your committer identity to.

Those checkboxes are only relevant if you:

- want to set the commit date to anything but "now"
- want to change the author identity of the commit when you amend the previous commit (usually, only the commit identity is set to yours, but the author identity is left alone).

Comment: Thanks. I always checked those every time. Those are a bit confusing but now it's clear.